# Writing regular expressions and rules in Sublime Text 2 syntax definitions

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm very interested in [Syntax Definitions for Sblime text 2](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html)

I've studied the basics but I don't know how to write RE (and rules) for smth like
`variable = sentense`, i.e. `myvar = func(foo, bar) + baz`

I can't write anything better than `^\s*([^=\n]+)=([^=\n]+\n)` (that doesn't work)
How to write this RE in proper way?

Also, i have some difficulties in defining RE for block

```
IF i FROM .. TO ..
    ...
ELSE
    ...
END IF
```

Hoe to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to write a parser. A regex won't work because the patterns may vary. You've already noticed it when you stated 'variable = sentence'.
For this, you can use spoofax or javacup for grammar definitions. I'll give you a snip in JavaCup:

Scanner issues: suppose 'variable' follows the pattern: (_|[a-zA-Z])(_|[a-zA-Z])*
and 'number' is: ([0-9])+
Note that number could be any decimal or int, but here I state it as that pattern, supposing my language only deals with integer (or whatever that pattern means :) ).

Now we can declare our grammar following the JavaCUP syntax. Which is more or less like:

expression ::= variable "=" sentence

sentence ::= sentence "+" sentence;
sentence ::= sentence "-" sentence;
sentence ::= sentence "*" sentence;
sentence ::= sentence "/" sentence;

sentence ::= number;

...and that goes further.

If you've never had any compiler's class, it may seems very difficult to see. Plus there is a lot of grammar's restrictions to avoiding infinity loop in the parser, depending on which you're using (RL or LL).

Anyway, the real answer for your question is: you can't do what you want only with regex, i'll need more concepts.

Comment: Ok. I agree that pure RE are not good idea. ST2 syntax definitions are  plists (xml), so for easy editing authors suggest to write definitions in some kind of json object and then convert them into plist (see link in question). My problem is that ST docs don't have enough examples on how to write common rules. They just explain syntax of json. Since there are a lot of syntax defs for many languages, I suppose that this is not impossible task.. I just don't know how to write this plists or jsons. May be there are any other docs on this theme?

Comment: I mean RE in syntax definitions is standart way to define syntaxes. The question is how to do that. (And I just want to write rules for code highliter for one rare programming language, nor parser, compiler or smth. else)

Comment: Do you have to use this ST2? I think the syntax in json files isn't human-readable enough. I mean, you can read it, but it is very tough.

Comment: I didn't find any other option to do this.

Comment: What do you want is to highlight some code in Sublime Text, isn't it? It has to be in Sublime Text? Because I know how to do this in Eclipse, if you're ok with that, I can help you. If you prefer, you can contact me through email, just use the tag [Stackoverflow] in the subject, only for a personal organization.

Comment: Thank you! But it is very interesting do do it with myself. I reread docs many times, and now I think I have some ideas how to do that!

Comment: Ok!! When you're more expert with it, and if you could, send me any material to learn it too. I also work with languages and compilers, and it would be cool to know ST2. I'm just without time to learn it.
Thank you!